# C# Application.Current.Shutdown() vs Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()

Tags: c#, xml, exception, exit

**From my knowledge today I would never try to kill or shut an app down. (At least I cannot think about a situation where I would [Security breach maybe?]). As devs we should always try to throw an exception and handle it somewhere in a higher level.**

---

I am working on a couple xml loading classes. And a lot of validation in there. There are about 100 situations where I have to quit the Application if the xml does not contain the correct values.

My problem is that when I call Application.Current.Shutdown(0); whenever an invalid Node is detected my App will **not** close immediatly. In fact it will run some "final" code that will throw exceptions due to those ivalid values. And I really don't want to catch exceptions for values that I already checked and found to be invalid.

There are a couple Questions here on stack about why not to kill the process ... I know. But is there some best practice for closing the Application whitout running additional code that will produce runtime exceptions or do I really have to catch all these exceptions just because the app may continue through that code?

Also, it seems that Application.Current.Shutdown(0); will allow the App to finish the current scope. I am totally confused, because I thought it should force all routines to return...

Thank you for any advice!
Noël

**EDIT:**
Let's say I can not open a file wich is essential for further execution. I get an ioexception...Now I need to shut the app. What are good design principles for this? I cannot fix the issue I need to close the app without running additional code that relies on the data in that file.

**EDIT 2**

```
//Retrieve printers in router.devs
_xmlContents.RouterDevsPrinter = getRouterDevsPrinter();

//Check cimgraph queue folder
node = loadNode(XmlDoc, getXPath(XPathVars.QueueFolder));
if (node == null) return false;
_xmlContents.CimgraphPlotQueue = StaticValues.addPathTrailingSlash(node.InnerText);
if (!Directory.Exists(_xmlContents.CimgraphPlotQueue))
{
    StaticValues.showFatalError("Folder not found:", "Could not find the following folder:" + "\"" + _xmlContents.CimgraphPlotQueue + "\"");
    return false;
}

//Check UserXml folder
node = loadNode(XmlDoc, getXPath(XPathVars.UsersXmlFolder));
if (node == null) return false;
_xmlContents.CustomXmlFolder = StaticValues.addPathTrailingSlash(node.InnerText);
if (!Directory.Exists(_xmlContents.CustomXmlFolder))
{
    StaticValues.showFatalError("Folder not found:", "Could not find the following folder:" + "\"" + _xmlContents.CustomXmlFolder + "\"");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why would you kill the application for invalid values? Why would you not want to catch those exceptions and handle them gracefully? Surely you need to provide some feedback to the user to allow them to fix the validation? - This sounds like bad design / code smell.

Comment: You can just `return` after calling that.

Comment: Well, this is about xml files managed by the administrator. And over 300 users are accessing those files. And they are not allowed to change any configuration (They also only have read-only access)

Comment: @tia Yea, I tried that! but this just returns one level up the stack and continues there...

Comment: Noel, even if they are read-only, just don't write to them? Crashing your own program just to spite the user seems very unfriendly to me

Comment: How about handling exceptions for a best practice? Sane programming practices aside - cause a StackOverflow and it will die

Comment: @NoelWidmer Well, you have to propagate the error until you can actually handle it in some way. An easy way to do this, of course, would be by using exceptions. Whether it's appropriate or not depends on what you're doing.

Comment: @Sayse I print an error like "invalid servername or whatever" and I call Application.Current.Shutdown(0); wich will not shutdown immediatly. Our useres usually report such issues to the helpdesk and we know how to deal with it. And there really is no way for any user to fix the ussue in this time.         But it seems you all want me to handle the exceptions somehow. What I could do is to catch each exception at top-stack and shut the app right there. That would prevent further execution, but it seems kinda stupid to me.

Comment: @NoelWidmer - Part of me wonders if you underestimate your users ability to discover setting/config files or similar. But the core problem is that even if a user misclicks on a button, any progress they have made within your application is lost. As a user, if you annoy/frustrate me one too many times and you have lost my business forever. The solution would be to just show the user a dialog with a chance to send a direct response to your support team, you can even include a stack trace and information in this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to your edit:

> Let's say I can not open a file wich is essential for further
>   execution. I get an ioexception...Now I need to shut the app. What are
>   good design principles for this? I cannot fix the issue I need to
>   close the app without running additional code that relies on the data
>   in that file.

usually in this scenario we simply try some code, handle the issues we foresee gracefully and simply discontinue execution of the program depending on the result of the previous action...

Try / Catch / Finally is perfect for this... See this example:

```
        private static bool TryOpenFile()
        {
            try
            {
                // Attempt to open file.
                return true;
            }
            catch (IOException exception)
            {
                // Log the error.
                // Unable to open file... do something for the user.
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Log.
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Can do things here that should always happen regardless.
            }
        }
```

Then in the calling method I would probably write something like this...

```
if (TryOpenFile())
{
     // File can be opened... continue on my merry way.
}
else
{
     // Could not open file.
     return;
}
```

Comment: This is quite a bit more in depth than what I do at the moment. Thank you for this! It just feels a bit much that I have to write that much code just to check one setting. I will improve my code based on this.

Comment: Really? Its a simple try / catch statement... The time this code takes you to write is nothing compared to the amount of time you are going to need in order to debug a program that has no error handling, validation or logging.

Answer (score 1):

Do you validate before you start any work? If so, don't even show the form. Just show a message and your SubMain will naturally exit.

Do you validate after you start some work? If so, just do `Form.Close`. You can optionally set some form wide configuration to ignore any validation. You probably use Form.Closing event, so put it there.

You did not provide any reason why the application should suddenly crash on the user. So neither `Application.Current.Shutdown()` nor `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` are appropriate.

As mentioned by peers, it helps to let users know what they need to do. Rather than just saying "Error" (which I've seen some apps do), it is more helpful to know that "An application has crashed because there is a configuration error. Please send below stack trace to some email or call this person at this extension (or submit a ticket via this tracking system etc.)".

Comment: I would recommend that you include something along the lines of my comment about using the information about why the application is closing before you actually call `Form.Close`.. I.E " The solution would be to just show the user a dialog with a chance to send a direct response to your support team, you can even include a stack trace and information in this ;) "

Comment: @Sayse: Agree, I added to my answer.

Comment: @Sayse grrr, I am showing a supporting message, but it is not meant for the user. It is for the administrator. I even show the line and char position of the errors (in the xml). haha :) Altough it is a good tip if I did wouldn't do that already

Comment: @NoelWidmer ... Do you want someone to tell you what you are doing is correct? Justification? Or are you here to learn and improve!?

Comment: @BenjaminPaul Sorry, I did not wanted to offend you. Ah no, I was looking for a quick way of solving the issue and we kinda got away from my acctual problem. Thank you all anyway! And I didn't mean to. Sorry again :) Peace :)

Comment: @NoelWidmer: It is very good that you are logging in the right information for the administrator to have a look. But users also like to be part of the action. Let them know they are important and ask them to help you (even if it's as simple as sending an email or making a phone call).

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your application to not require the `Shutdown` or `Kill` call.  That using a sledgehammer.

Let the normal flow of the program end when the invalid state occurs.

Comment: I think I am just trying to make my code simpler wich obviusly isn't a good idea. Thank you all  for your input! I will accept both answers since they kinda point into the right direction. I just hoped for a way to terminate without having to return to top-level... Seems like that would be the best way then... Thanks!